# Partitioned View : using the CHECK CONSTRAINT

Tags: view, sql-server-2008-r2

In order to store a huge amount of data in a SQL Server 2008 R2 Express database, I am splitting the data to several databases, creating a new "partition" for each month.

This post : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019.aspx shows how to help the query optimizer to find data faster among my partitions.

However, when querying data on my View between dates that only match an empty partition, the query plan shows that it's seeking among every partitions. I can't figure out why though.

My view is very simple :

```
SELECT A.Gohan, B.Goku
FROM [Feb2011].[dbo].[A]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Feb2011].[dbo].[B]
UNION ALL
SELECT A.Gohan, B.Goku
FROM [Mar2011].[dbo].[A]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Mar2011].[dbo].[B]
UNION ALL
...
```

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partitioned views are not supported in the SQL Server Express edition.

Check *SQL Server Features Not Supported in SQL Server Express* section of the [SQL Server Express Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165636.aspx) page on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

This is because these aren't real partitions. If you build an index on each database table based on date, then it will check that index and quickly return 0 rows. If it were truly partitioned, then you would get the behavior you expect. But it's not, so it will check every table in the `union` statement to bring back an empty resultset.

So long as the query plan is showing a `seek`, and not a `scan`, I wouldn't worry one bit about it, since `seeks` are rather quick. Depending on the `scan`, though, you may also be okay (it's not a black and white rule).